# ¿Cómo eliminar un STR de un WHILE loop cuando se cumple la condición?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Python donde el usuario crea una contraseña, y al digitar nuevamente la contraseña, si coinciden, se finaliza con un "Contraseña correcta", sino, el bucle se mantiene con "Contraseña incorrecta" "Introduzca su contraseña", hasta que coincidan.

```
def password():
    key = str(input("Digite una contraseña: "))
    password = ""
    while password != key:
        password = str(input("Introduzca su contraseña: "))
        print(" ")
        print("Contraseña incorrecta")
    print("Contraeña correcta")
```

Cuando `password = key`, la salida es

```
Contraseña incorrecta
Contraeña correcta
```

No sé cómo eliminar "Contraseña incorrecta" cuando la condición se cumple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solución 1** cambiando el código :

```
def check_password():
    key = input("Digite una contraseña : ")
    password = input("Introduzca su contraseña: ")
    if (password != key):
        print("Contraseña incorrecta\n")
        check_password()
    else:
        print("Contraseña correcta")

check_password()
```

En la función `check_password()` ejecutamos y alamacenamos en las variables `key` y `password` dos claves.

Seguido de esto, en la sentencia `if` decimos que si `password` no es igual a `key` nos devuelve un mensaje de error y vuelva a ejecutar la función `check_password()` ejecutando así una sentencia recursiva (la función se llama a si misma de nuevo).

En la condición `else` decimos `Contraseña correcta` ya que si no se cumple la función del `if` quiere decir que las contraseñas coinciden

Ahora te añado otra posible función con el código que tienes para que tengas dos posibles formas de realizar esto.

**Solución 2** en base a tu código :

```
def check_password():
    key = input("Digite una contraseña: ")
    password = str(input("Introduzca su contraseña: "))
    while password != key:
        password = input("\nContraseña incorrecta, introduzca su contraseña de nuevo: ")
    print("Contraeña correcta")
check_password()
```

Primero de todo, no es necesario que la variable `password` la inicies fuera de tu while como hacias con `password = ""`, primero le asignamos el valor y comprobamos si coinciden. Si no es así, se pide que se entre de nuevo el valor a `password`. Esto se ejecuta hasta que las contraseñas coinciden.

Comment: Si esto te ha funcionado escribe un comentario y valida la respuesta, en caso de alguna duda o aclaración que necesites escribe un comentario de igual forma!

Comment: No es necesario usar `str()`. La función `input()` siempre devuelve un string.

Comment: @CandidMoe solucionado, era copy paste del codigo ;D

Comment: Sí funcionó, muchas gracias